# Fixing some variable issues in JS and JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging, web-applications

I am learning to program in javascript so that I can add some functionality to my websites. I am trying to make a simple blackjack game in the browser and now I have no idea what is going on.

I have 2 functions: the first function `randomCard()` generates a random card, the second function `deal()` uses a for loop to use the first function twice and stores the cards into an array. I'd rather not combine these functions because there are other spots in the future that it will be way more convenient to keep them separate. I use the deal function on two objects, user and dealer with the method hand.

Now here is the problem, when I log these values to the console (not final, just for testing), they are the same every time and I have no idea why. But when I just log the `deal()` function a bunch they are all different (see bottom of script).

I can't figure it out and would greatly appreciate help, here is all my code so far.

I'm using **jQuery 1.11.0**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Blackjack Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button type="submit" id="deal">Deal</button>
        <p class="user">
            Your cards: 
        </p>
        <p class="dealer">
            The dealers cards: 
        </p>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            // gives the user and dealer a DOM element
            var $user_cards = $('.user');
            var $dealer_cards = $('.dealer');

            // hides the DOM elements until the game has started
            $($user_cards).hide();
            $($dealer_cards).hide();

            // jQuery var for DOM element to start the game
            var $deal = $('#deal');

            // var to track if the deal button  has been clicked
            var click = 0;

            function randomCard() {
                // random number between 0 and 10
                var j = Math.random() * 10;
                // round that number into a var called card
                var card = Math.round(j);   
                // if card is 0, assign a J Q or K by making a random number again
                if (card === 0) {
                    //another random number
                    var k = Math.random() * 10; 
                    // checks random number and assign J Q or K                     
                    if (k <= 4) {
                        card = 'J';
                    } else if (k <= 7) {
                        card = 'Q';
                    }
                    else {
                        card = 'K';
                    }
                }
                // value of the function is a single card
                return card;
            }

            // empty array to store cards
            var cards = [];

            function deal() {
                // var to start for loop 
                var i = 0;              
                // start for loop 
                for (i; i < 2; i++) {
                    // add a random card to the i^th index of cards
                    cards[i] = randomCard();
                }
                // value fo function is array of two cards
                return cards;
            }

            $($deal).click(function() {

                // make the game start check = 1
                click++;
                // check to see if the game started
                if (click === 1) {
                    // make the button disappear when game has started
                    $($deal).fadeToggle('fast');

                    // makes the player DOM elements appear when game is started
                    $($user_cards).fadeToggle(2000);
                    $($dealer_cards).fadeToggle(2000);
                }

                // make an object for the user and store hand under user.hand
                var user = {
                    hand: deal()
                };

                // make an object for the dealer and store hand under dealer.hand
                var dealer = {
                    hand: deal()
                };

                console.log(user.hand + " " + dealer.hand);
                console.log(deal());
                console.log(deal());
                console.log(deal());
                console.log(deal());
                console.log(deal());
                console.log(deal());


            }); // $deal.click() end

        }); // document.ready() end

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to do `$($user_cards).hide();`.  You can just do `$user_cards.hide();`.  `.hide()` is a method of a jQuery object and `$user_cards` is already a jQuery object so you can just use it directly.  No need to create yet another jQuery object by doing `$($user_cards)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news and bad news:

**The good news**

Your code actually works.

If you replace

```
console.log(deal());
```

with

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(deal()));
```

then you'll get the result you expect.

**The bad news**

The Chrome console is "live" -- meaning it shows the *current* value of an object -- not the value at the time you logged it.

(If you ask me, I'd call this a *bug* -- but my vote doesn't count.)

You have two solutions.

**Solution 1**

Use `console.log` and `stringify` as I have done.

**Solution 2**

Make `deal` return a new and different object by moving re-arranging your code slightly.

```
function deal() {
  // MOVE THESE LINES INSIDE THE FUNCTION.
  // empty array to store cards
  var cards = [];

  // var to start for loop 
  var i = 0;              
  // start for loop 
  for (i; i < 2; i++) {
    // add a random card to the i^th index of cards
    cards[i] = randomCard();
  }
  // value fo function is array of two cards
  return cards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters

**Defining getters and setters**

A getter is a method that gets the value of a specific property. A setter is a method that sets the value of a specific property. You can define getters and setters on any predefined core object or user-defined object that supports the addition of new properties. The syntax for defining getters and setters uses the object literal syntax.

Applied to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blackjack Game</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button type="submit" id="deal">Deal</button>
    <p class="user">
        Your cards: 
    </p>
    <p class="dealer">
        The dealers cards: 
    </p>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // gives the user and dealer a DOM element
        var $user_cards = $('.user');
        var $dealer_cards = $('.dealer');

        // hides the DOM elements until the game has started
        $($user_cards).hide();
        $($dealer_cards).hide();

        // jQuery var for DOM element to start the game
        var $deal = $('#deal');

        // var to track if the deal button  has been clicked
        var click = 0;

        function randomCard() {
            // random number between 0 and 10
            var j = Math.random() * 10;
            // round that number into a var called card
            var card = Math.round(j);   
            // if card is 0, assign a J Q or K by making a random number again
            if (card === 0) {
                //another random number
                var k = Math.random() * 10; 
                // checks random number and assign J Q or K                     
                if (k <= 4) {
                    card = 'J';
                } else if (k <= 7) {
                    card = 'Q';
                }
                else {
                    card = 'K';
                }
            }
            // value of the function is a single card
            return card;
        }

        // empty array to store cards
        var cards = [];

        function deal() {
            // var to start for loop 
            var i = 0;              
            // start for loop 
            for (i; i < 2; i++) {
                // add a random card to the i^th index of cards
                cards[i] = randomCard();
            }
            // value fo function is array of two cards
            return cards;
        }

        $($deal).click(function() {

            // make the game start check = 1
            click++;
            // check to see if the game started
            if (click === 1) {
                // make the button disappear when game has started
                $($deal).fadeToggle('fast');

                // makes the player DOM elements appear when game is started
                $($user_cards).fadeToggle(2000);
                $($dealer_cards).fadeToggle(2000);
            }

            // make an object for the user and store hand under user.hand
            var user = {
                //hand: function() { return deal() }
                get hand() { return deal(); },
            };

            // make an object for the dealer and store hand under dealer.hand
            var dealer = {
                //hand: function() { return deal() }
                get hand() { return deal(); },
            };

            console.log(user.hand + " " + dealer.hand);
            console.log(deal());
            console.log(deal());
            console.log(deal());
            console.log(deal());
            console.log(deal());
            console.log(deal());


        }); // $deal.click() end

    }); // document.ready() end

    </script>
</body>
```